# sizeof instance of std::vector returns wrong number of elements in the vector

Tags: c++

I have a cycle, that defines a vector of GLfloat vertices coordinates. (three 1.0f floats describe the color, it doesn't matter)

```cpp
std::vector<GLfloat> verticesUnitPoints;

float xCurrent = -1.0f;

for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
{
    float yOffset = 0.01f;

            //first vertex
    verticesUnitPoints.push_back(xCurrent);
    verticesUnitPoints.push_back(yOffset);
    verticesUnitPoints.push_back(0.0f);

    verticesUnitPoints.push_back(1.0f);
    verticesUnitPoints.push_back(1.0f);
    verticesUnitPoints.push_back(1.0f);

            //second vertex
    verticesUnitPoints.push_back(xCurrent);
    verticesUnitPoints.push_back(-yOffset);
    verticesUnitPoints.push_back(0.0f);

    verticesUnitPoints.push_back(1.0f);
    verticesUnitPoints.push_back(1.0f);
    verticesUnitPoints.push_back(1.0f);

    xCurrent += 0.25f;
}
```

I also have a glBufferData function, that must create a buffer with enough place for all vector elements.

```cpp
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verticesUnitPoints) * sizeof(GLfloat), &verticesUnitPoints[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

But as I can see in output window, only small part of all vertices is rendered.

I can easily fix it by just increasing the multiplier of sizeof(verticesUnitPoints) but I find this solution horrible.

Comment: **`verticesUnitPoints.size()`** instead of `sizeof(verticesUnitPoints)`.

Comment: Please see the complete reference on [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).  What is strange is that you know about `push_back`, but not know about `size()`, which is very basic functionality that vector provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof(verticesUnitPoints)` returns size of `std::vector` class (not instance), which is fixed for any number of elements.

In order to obtain this number use member function `std::vector::size` (`verticesUnitPoints.size()`)